# calculating complexity of a function

Tags: big-o, time-complexity

We have homework to write a pseudocode that sorts an array from smallest to biggest. this is what i wrote:

```
Function sorting(list)
;define
index = 0
for i in list.length:
    ;take first element from unsorted part in array
    small = list[0+i]
    ;length of unsorted list
    for n in list.length-i:
        ;runs on all elements in list starting from unsorted part (i)
        if list[n+i] <= small:
            ;if it is smallest, take smallest place
            small = list[n+i]
            ;save it's index
            index = n+i 
    put where the smallest is, the first element in unsorted part
    list[index] = array[i]
    ;put in first place of unsorted the smallest. we actually exchange smallest with first
    array[i] = small
return list
```

so for the first loop, i do n times what's in it,

n(1+....)

but the second loop, it always gets smaller, i have no idea how to calculate it.

please help

Ps, I do not need the big o, i know it is O(n²), i need the formula of the complexity

Answer (score 1):

It's O(n^2).

You may want to learn different sorting algorithms, like [quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort), [mergesort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort), [heapsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort) and [bubblesort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort).

Comment: I know. Besides answering his question, I provided him some material to study different algorithms.

Comment: @libik - I think that the author's intention would have been to mention `bucket sort`...

Comment: actually this is selection sort

Answer (score 1):

Your approximate number of steps is n + (n-1) + (n-2) + ... + 1. This equals to n * (n + 1) / 2. In complexity terms, it's O(n^2), or naturally speaking, the number of elementary operations is proportional to the square of the input size.

Comment: I know what is the O(), but i need the complexity

Comment: A very similar example explained step by step can be found here - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms#Evaluating_run-time_complexity

Comment: Actually, O() is a representation of the complexity. I have just found out a very nice complexity "cheat sheet": http://bigocheatsheet.com/ . Quicksort is a interesting example of the great difference between Average (read "real-life") and Worst Case.